# new method declaration in derived interface

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop

I lately studied some code and encountered a derived interface that declares `new` method with exactly the same name and signature as a base interface:

```
public interface IBase
{
    Result Process(Settings settings);
}

public interface IDerived : IBase
{
    new Result Process(Settings settings);
}
```

I'm wondering if there could be a reason for this. According to my understanding I can safely remove the latter method declaration and leave `IDerived` empty without possibly breaking any code using it. Am I wrong?

P.S. If this matters, these interface declarations also have the following attributes: `ComVisible(true)`, `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)` and `Guid(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you *may* be able to get rid of it - but if you get rid of the method in `IDerived`, it's not actually the same, strictly speaking. An implementation can actually provide two different methods to implement the two interface methods differently.

For example:

```
using System;

public interface IBase
{
    void Process();
}

public interface IDerived : IBase
{
    new void Process();
}

public class FunkyImpl : IDerived
{
    void IBase.Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IBase.Process");
    }

    void IDerived.Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IDerived.Process");
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var funky = new FunkyImpl();
        IBase b = funky;
        IDerived d = funky;
        b.Process();
        d.Process();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jon. So I will adjust my question a bit: if I remove IDerived.Process method and all the code using it will compile is there theoretical possibility to introduce some runtime bugs into the code?

Comment: @user835103: If all the code still compiles (all code both implementing and using the interfaces) then it should be okay.